# Why does the && operator produce the type of the second operand

Tags: types, typescript

The TypeScript specification states in §4.15.6 about the `&&` operator:

> The && operator permits the operands to be of any type and produces a **result of the same type as the second operand**.

In Javascript, the `&&` operator returns the first operand if it is falsy, otherwise it returns the second operand ([see ECMA-262 §11.11](http://es5.github.com/#x11.11)).

That means that if the left operand is falsy, `&&` will return a value that matches the type of the left operand. For example,

```
typeof ( false && {}      ) === "boolean" // true
typeof ( ''    && 1       ) === "string"  // true
typeof ( null  && "hello" ) === "object"  // true
typeof ( NaN   && true    ) === "number"  // true
```

Typescript, according to the rule quoted above, would *incorrectly* predict the types of the above expressions to be `Object`, `Number`, `String` and `Boolean`, respectively.

Am I missing something? Is there a good reason to make the type of an `&&` expression match the type of the second operand? Shouldn't the result type behave like the `||` operator, and return the best common type of the two operands, and `Any` if there is no best common type?

Comment: What is the type of `||`? What about `a ? b : c`? If I understood you correctly, `a && b` is equivalent to `a ? a : b` (except a is evaluated twice in the latter example)

Comment: @ReyCharles `&&` is like `!a ? a : b` and `||` is like `a ? a : b`.

Comment: Right, sorry. That was a brainfart. My real question is what are the types of `a || b` and `a ? b : c`. Interesting question, btw.

Comment: @ReyCharles TypeScript says the type of `a || b` is `Any` unless the two operands have matching types. In `a ? b : c`, if I recall correctly, TypeScript requires that `b` and `c` are the same type.

Comment: Update: this works properly now in Typescript 2 if `strictNullChecks` is enabled.

Comment: @Guessit'sbeenaminute That's not correct. `a && b` is equivalent to `a ? b : a`. For example, let's say `const a = "dog"; const b = "cat";` If you evaluate `a && b` in the console, you will get `'cat'`, whereas `a ? !a : b` will give you `false`.

Comment: @PeterOlson True

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Long story short, there's no solution here that pleases everyone.

Consider this common idiom:

```
var customer = GetCustomer(...); // of type 'Customer'
var address = customer && customer.address;
if(address) {
    printAddressLabel(address); // Signature: (Address) => void
} else {
    // Couldn't find the customer or the customer has no address on file
}
```

It'd be pretty lame to give up and decide that 'address' is 'any' because there's no best common type between Customer and Address.

In the majority of cases where the && operator is used, either the types *already* match, or && is being used in a value-coalescing manner like above. In either case, returning the type of the right operand gives the user the expected type.

While the type safety is technically breaking down at this point, it's not doing so in a way that's likely to result in an error. Either you're going to test the resultant value for truthiness (in which case the type is more or less irrelevant), or you're going to use the presumptive right operand for some operation (the example above doing both).

If we look at the examples you listed and pretend the left operand is indeterminately truthy or falsy and then try to write sane code that would operate on the return value, it becomes a lot clearer - there's just not much you can *do* with 'false && {}' that isn't already going into an 'any' argument position or truthiness test.

---

**Addendum**

Since some people were not convinced by the above, here's a different explanation.

Let's pretend for a moment that the TypeScript type system added three new types: `Truthy<T>`, `Falsy<T>`, and `Maybe<T>`, representing possible truthy/falsy values of type `T`. The rules for these types are as follows:

1. `Truthy<T>` behaves exactly like `T`
2. You can't access any properties of `Falsy<T>`
3. An expression of type `Maybe<T>`, when used as the condition in an `if` block, becomes a `Truthy<T>` in the body of that same `if` block and a `Falsy<T>` in the `else` block

This would let you do things like this:

```
function fn(x: Maybe<Customer>) {
   if(x) {
      console.log(x.address); // OK
   } else {
      console.log(x.phone); // Error: x is definitely falsy
   }
   console.log(x.name); // Warning: x might be falsy!
}
```

Pretty good so far. Now we can figure out what the type rules are for the && operator.

- `Truthy<T> && x` should be an error - if the left side is known to be truthy, you should have just written `x`
- `Falsy<T> && x` should be an error - if the left side is known to be falsy, `x` is unreachable code
- `Maybe<T> && x` should produce... what?

We know the result of `Maybe<T> && x` will be either a falsy value of type `T`, or `x`. It cannot produce `Truthy<T>` (unless `T` == the type of `x` in which case this entire discussion is moot). Let's call this new type `Falsy<T> XOR Maybe<U>`.

What should the rules of `Falsy<T> XOR Maybe<U>` be?

- Clearly, you can't use properties of `T` on it. If the value is of type `T`, it's falsy, and not safe for use.
- You should be able to use it as a `Maybe<U>`, since `Falsy<T>` and `Falsy<U>` have the same behaviors
- You shouldn't be able to use properties of `U`, because the value still might be falsy.
- If you use it in an `if` test, then it should become a `Truthy<U>` in the block of that `if` statement

In other words, `Falsy<T> XOR Maybe<U>` **is** `Maybe<U>`. It follows all the same rules. You don't need to complicate the type system at all here by adding this weird `XOR` type, because a type that fits all the specifications you need already exists.

This is a bit like giving someone a box and saying "This is either an empty box of garbage, or a full box of recyclables". You can safely empty the contents of the box into the recycling bin.

Comment: But this really isn't the way that it works... If you write `alert(typeof(false && 'hello'))` you get `'boolean'`, not `'string'`. In fact, that typescript code compiles into identical javascript. Are you claiming that the && operator does not behave exactly like javascript?

Comment: && does what && does, TypeScript or not. The question is what the *compile-time* type of the result should be when the arguments aren't of the same type. In the case "false && 'hello'", the reasonable options are bool, string, and any; the explanation above is why 'string' is the type chosen rather than 'any' or 'bool'.

Comment: @Prestaul But with alert(typeof(true && 'hello')) you get string. The compiler must pick a type. For an expression of the form A && B it picks the type of B. As Ryan explains, that seems to work best in most situation if not strictly accurate. The other choices are worse, IMHO.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. It still upsets my sensibilities about compile-time type accuracy, but I guess practical value trumps technical correctness here.

Comment: @chuckj & Ryan Cavanaugh, you are saying that for the purposes of compilation it assumes the type of the right-hand operand... got it. That makes me extremely uncomfortable... As Peter said, it upsets my sensibilities about compile-time accuracy. It just feels wrong. (Although, honestly, strongly typed javascript feels wrong to me.)

Comment: Sorry, but this is absolutely bonkers.  A type system is supposed to provide guarantees, not be some pirate code of vague guidelines.  A RIGHT answer (i.e., one that doesn't throw out the whole point of a type system) is to have TWO sets of logical operators.  One, && and ||, for JavaScript's "we don't need no steenkin' types" world, with result type `any`, and one, say &&& and |||, for TypeScript which have both sane semantics and useful type rules.  I'm absolutely flabbergasted that something so fundamental is deliberately broken in TypeScript.

Comment: Long alternate explanation added.

Comment: I just had a wonderful bug catching session with React.

I had `const Component = (props: { model?: Model }) => props.model?.getId()`. And was using it this way: `const pass = false; const model = new Model(); return ( <Component model={ pass && model } /> );`

This code failed, because `props.model` was `false`, and `props.model.getId()` was always called. I blame TypeScript here, because it inferred `pass && model` type to be `Model` instead of `boolean | Model`.

It's very appealing to use `boolean && value` to conditionally pass react properties, but is a wrong pattern :(

Answer (score 3):

The language specification is not maintained, and wrong in this case. The result type of the `&&` operator is the union of the type of the right-hand side and the falsy values of the left hand side.

From the [TypeScript 2.0 release notes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-and-non-undefined-type-guards):

```
// Compiled with --strictNullChecks
declare function f(x: number): string;
let x: number | null | undefined;
// ..
let b = x && f(x); // Type of b is string | 0 | null | undefined
```