# TypeScript does not detect union type with an && operator

Tags: typescript

In the below example x is actually a union type of 'boolean | string' but TypeScript considers it a string. Is this a bug or am I missing something?

```
var x:string = false && "foo";
```

Comment: When you say `x` is actually a union type.... It's clearly of type `string` in your question. Unless I am missing something?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/12694771/1704166

Comment: I declare it a string type but would have expected TS to infer a union type and throw an error. @basarat informed me the spec specifies the behavior though so I understand it now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this a bug or am I missing something

This is by design. According to spec the inferred type from `&&` is the type of the *last* expression. So the *inferred* type of the following is `string`:

```
var x = false && "foo";
```

This to support a common JavaScript pattern :

```
var something = foo && foo.bar && foo.bar.bas;
```

Here it would be great if `something` was of type `foo.bar.bas` and that is exactly what typescript inferrs.

Comment: Thanks! Having && always be of type: 'boolean | type of last expression' seems to be more correct but if it's at least spelled out in the spec that's better than a bug. :)