# TypeScript && operator doesn't produce the type of the second operand

Tags: typescript

Some previous SO questions describe that the inferred type from `&&` is the type of the last expression.

- [TypeScript does not detect union type with an && operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30904042/94148)
- [Why does the && operator produce the type of the second operand](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12693787/94148)

But TypeScript 2.4.2 reports error on below code:

```
function isQuerySql(sql: string): boolean {
  return sql && _.trimStart(sql).toLowerCase().startsWith('select');
}
```

> error TS2322: Type 'boolean | ""' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
>   Type '""' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.

I can't figure out what's wrong. `_.trimStart(sql).toLowerCase().startsWith('select')` is inferred as boolean. Where does `""` come?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the string `sql` is empty the function `isQuerySql` will return the expression before the `&&`, hence it returns an empty string:

```
isQuerySql("") === ""
isQuerySql("select") == true
isQuerySql("foo") == false
```

So the return type is indeed `boolean | ""`

You can sort this by making the first comparison explicit:

```
function isQuerySql(sql: string): boolean {
  return sql !== "" && _.trimStart(sql).toLowerCase().startsWith('select');
}
```

Or forcing it to a boolean if you need to catch null and undefined as well:

```
function isQuerySql(sql: string): boolean {
  return !!sql && _.trimStart(sql).toLowerCase().startsWith('select');
}
```

Or maybe this:

```
function isQuerySql(sql: string): boolean {
  return sql? _.trimStart(sql).toLowerCase().startsWith('select') : false;
}
```