# Type 'Observable<boolean | "">' is not assignable to type 'Observable<boolean>' TS2322

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngrx

I'm selecting from NgRx store `@ngrx/store": "7.3.0"`.

```
// typeof state.id == string

export const selectIsSomethingPresent = createSelector(selector, state => {
  // standard null check
  return state.id && state.id !== "12345";
});
```

and I'm assigning it to an Observable

```
isSomethingPresent$ !: Observable<boolean>;

someMethod() {
  this.isSomethingPresent$ = this.store.select(selectIsSomethingPresent);
}
```

I'm getting this error:

`Type 'Observable<boolean | "">' is not assignable to type 'Observable<boolean>'.`

Why does typescript act like that?

fyi `return ("12345" && true)` throws same error.

Answer (score 2):

Because `state.id` type is a `string`, an empty string && true will return an empty string and not a boolean so you need to convert `state.id` to `boolean`

```
return Boolean(state.id) && state.id !== "12345";
```

Comment: Them why `return "12345" && true` throws the same same error?

Comment: @KacperCieluch see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12693787/why-does-the-operator-produce-the-type-of-the-second-operand. Note you can use `!!state.id` instead of `Boolean(state.id)`

Comment: @AndrewAllen IMO it is more readable to use `Boolean()` then `!!`